# How to Configure WCF Service Operation Auto Start

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I've developed a WCF service that has only one operation("start") and once it's called, It actively Listens to a specific port.

I want to call this Operation every time the applicationpool is started. But i didn't find information about it.

I've search intensively through the net and what i found was instructions about how to autostart the service, which does not include how to call the WCF Service Operation on Applicationpool Start.

**I tried two approaches yet:**

One using a class with the appInitialize method inside the folder app_code of the deployed service. And in this class i called the start operation.
Didn't work, but the appInitialize don't even get called.

[step-by-step appInitialize method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tdevere/archive/2014/09/23/use-iis-application-initialization-in-iis-to-prime-wcf-services.aspx)

The second approach was through configuration of the file applicationHosts.config to configure Auto-Start for the service.
This also fails and the atribute "serviceAutoStartMode" were not recognized. However this is the start of the WCF Service and not WCF Service Operation call.

[step-by-step configurating Auto-Start to a WCF Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

**So my question is:**

Is there any way of calling the WCF service operation on start of the application pool, iis, or other recommendable event?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS 7+ and have App Fabric installed, you can use AppFabric Auto-Start feature.

It's like Auto-Start you've read about, and it's easily configured in IIS.
This link has a good example:
[appfabric-auto-start-feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/29/how-using-appfabric-auto-start-feature-to-avoid-warm-up-delays-for-iis-hosted-wcf-receive-locations.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Ricardo, I Finally put it working. The missing piece was quite simple. It was a configuration in applicationHost.config preloadEnable = "true" . after adding this line to the applicationHost.config in the sites section I was able to have my Operation being called automatically :)

Comment: @Nelssen, as far as I know, "preloadEnable" node need to install an initialization component:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization. Did you install this component?

Comment: Hi Kerwen, I don't remember quite well at the moment. If that's required It was probably already installed. cheers